# Accessing accelerometer from jni

Tags: java, android, java-native-interface

I'm trying to make an **android** app in which I need to access accelerometer in **jni**.

**java** code :

```
mSensorManager = (SensorManager)getSystemService(SENSOR_SERVICE);         
mAccelerometer = mSensorManager.getDefaultSensor(Sensor.TYPE_ACCELEROMETER);
```

**jni** code :

```
jclass cls_context = env->FindClass("android/content/Context");
jfieldID tService = env->GetStaticFieldID(cls_context, "SENSOR_SERVICE","Ljava/lang/String;");
jstring jstr = (jstring)env->GetStaticObjectField(cls_context, tService);

//getSystemService(SENSOR_SERVICE);
jclass cls_act = env->GetObjectClass(activity);
jmethodID GetSystemService = env->GetMethodID(cls_act,"getSystemService","(Ljava/lang/String;)Ljava/lang/Object;");
jobject systemservice = env->CallObjectMethod(activity,GetSystemService,jstr);

//getDefaultSensor(Sensor.TYPE_ACCELEROMETER);
jclass sensormanager = env->GetObjectClass(systemservice);
jmethodID getdefaultsensor = env->GetMethodID(sensormanager, "getDefaultSensor", "(I)Landroid/hardware/Sensor;");
jobject sensor = env->CallObjectMethod(systemservice, getdefaultsensor, "Sensor.TYPE__ACCELEROMETER");
```

But `jobject sensor` is getting `null`.

Comment: problem is solved :)

Comment: _"problem is solved"_ isn't particularly useful to others coming across this question. What exactly was the solution?

Comment: you can't call getDefaultSensor() directly by "Sensor.TYPE_ACCELEROMETER.
you have to first create a jint type object of Sensor.TYPE_ACCELEROMETER

Answer (score 0):

`Sensor.TYPE_ACCELEROMETER` is an inlined constant of type int and has value `1`, which should be passed there.

But anyway those 2 lines split into 9 lines of JNI code looks bad. Wouldn't it be better to leave those original lines of Java code and then just call it from JNI?